# Get edge with maximum weight to every node in MST using DFS

Tags: java, depth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a minimum spanning tree and I am using DFS to traverse it where the datastructure of my graph is an adjancancy list. I want to get the edge with the **maximum weight** to every node from the **source** and store it in an array, this is what I have so far:

```
void recDFS(int currVertex, int source, int[] visited, int maxWeight){

   visited[currVertex] = 1;
   Vector<IntegerPair> neighbours = MSTAdjList.get(currVertex);

   for(int j = 0; j < neighbours.size(); j++){

     int neighbourWeight = neighbours.get(j)._second // get weight of neighbour
     int neighbourIndex = neighbours.get(j)._first; // get index of neighbour

     if (neighbourWeight > maxWeight)
        maxWeight = neighbourWeight;

     bigArrayWithValues[source][neighbourIndex] = maxWeight; // Store each value

     recDFS(neighbourIndex, source, visited, maxWeight); // Call next neighbour

   }    
}
```

This won't work because when the recursion breaks, the value of maxWeight will still have the  "old" value, while I want the edge with max weight to each node from the **source** that is fixed.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give an example.